# Is there anyway to change my date format using date-fns?

Tags: node.js, momentjs, date-fns

I have been trying to change my date format, stored in the database as 202102, 202012 corresponding to 2021 Feb and 2020 December respectively to the MMM.yy format that is Feb-21 and Dec-20 respectively. Have tried to use the 'date-fns' library but have not been able to succeed. All and any help appreciated, project is built in nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) is an option for you, it's as easy as:

```js
const result = moment("202102", "YYYYMM").format("MMM-YY");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. Did not want to use moment as I read it is a quite big library and the same can be achieved using date-fns too, but I realise thats not the case (:

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the input strings, create a new Date object, then format using the built-in [Date.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) method to convert the date format:

```js
const inputs = ["200501", "202012", "202102", "202107", "202210"];

function convertDateFormat(input) {
    const date = new Date(+input.substr(0,4), +input.substr(4,2) - 1, 1);
    return date.toLocaleString('en', { year: '2-digit', month: 'short' } ).replace(' ','-');
}

inputs.forEach(input => console.log(`Input: ${input}, Output: ${convertDateFormat(input)}`));
```